# Nutch and HBase for production

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nutch, gora

I am currently using Nutch 2.2.1 and HBase 0.90.4. I am expecting around 300K urls from about 10 URLS in seed. I have already generated so much while using Nutch 1.6. Since I want to manipulate data, I preferred to go Nutch 2.2.1 + HBase route. But I get all sorts of weird errors and crawl doesn't seem to progress.

Various errors such as:

1. **zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect.** - I get this more frequently
2. **bin/crawl: line 164: killed** - I get this error from fetch step and the crawling gets killed all of a sudden.
3. RSS parse error

I am using a all-in-one crawl command - `bin/crawl urls 1 http://localhost:8983/solr/ 10`

```
<crawl> <seed-dir> <crawl-id> <solr-url> <number of rounds>
```

Please suggest where am I going wrong. I have Nutch 2.2.1 [installed](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial) and HBase (standalone) installed as per the [Quick start guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html) recommended from Nutch site. I am not sure following HBase 0.90.4 standalone set up from **Quick** start guide link is sufficient to achieve 300K crawled urls.

---

Edit # 1: RSS Parse Error - log information

**Error tika.TikaParser - Error parsing http://www.###.###.##/###/abc.xml
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: RSS parse error**

Comment: The zookeeper reminds me some hbase-site.xml misconfiguration. Can you check where is your hbase-site.xml to be read by Nutch? (or copy from your HBase's conf/ to Nutch's conf/). The second, try `nutch fetch <...>` and paste logs. About your third, what do you mean with "RSS" parse error? I assume it is failing in the first loop.

Comment: Hey Alfonso! Thanks for your reply. I never thought about copying the hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml to Nutch/conf. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: I added more information on RSS parse error

Comment: Hi, archer. Sorry for the following bad news: seems no RSS parser for Nutch with Tika: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-887 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-888

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa No option on RSS for now I guess. But I have a more burning problem now. I have set up fetcher threads to be 20 in my nutch-site.xml but when I use bin/crawl script for Nutch 2.2.1, it seems to ignore my nutch-site.xml fetcher.threads 20 instead it considers threads 50. Please advise

Comment: I think the key that controls the number of threads is `fetcher.threads.fetch`